# type parameter error

Tags: haskell

I create my own type parameters as follow:

```
data Node a = Node a

data Cost = Int | Float

data Edge Node Cost = Edge ((Node,Node),Cost)

data Graph Edge = Graph [Edge]
```

And get an error:

Unexpected type `Node' where type variable expected
    In the declaration of`Edge Node Cost'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Type Constructors vs Data Constructors

You have to tag the types in a union type in haskell:

```
data Cost = Int | Float
```

should say

```
data Cost = I Int | F Float
```

Notice that this is because `Int` and `Float` are types. Example data would be `I 5` or `F 5.6`. We need data constructors too. `I` and `F` are data constructors here. `I :: Int -> Cost` and `F :: Float -> Cost`. They're functions that turn Ints or Floats into Costs. You can have a constructor that doesn't take an argument, for example, as in your comment,

```
data Bool = True | False
```

Here True and False are constructors, not types. Example data would be just `True` or `False`. You do have to have constructors every time, which is why we need to tag the types `Int` and `Float`

The definition

```
data Node a = Node a
```

is a bit confusing, because on the left hand side, `Node` is a sort of type function we call a type constructor, and has kind `* -> *`, but on the right hand side `Node` is a data constructor of type `a -> Node a`. Example data: `Node "hello"` of type `Node String`. This would be less confusing if we wrote

```
data Node a = N a
```

So `Node` is the type constructor and `N` is the data constructor. This gives sample data `N "Hello"` of type `Node String`. For this sort of definition, we haven't made a lot of difference, so we tend to say

```
newtype Node a = N a
```

because the compiler can optimise it away in most cases, but we get type safety at the source code end.

### Type Constructors need types

You also need

```
data Edge a = Edge ((Node a,Node a),Cost)
```

because `Node` is a type constructor (it has kind `* -> *`) so you have to always give it a type to work on. I've given it `a` so you can make your node out of anything.

However, you don't need the brackets, and a union of Int and Float is probably not as useful as allowing any cost type, by using lower case `cost` instead of the fixed type `Cost`

```
data Edge a cost = Edge (Node a) (Node a) cost
```

(If you want to make sure no-one ever makes an edge out of any cost that is non-numerical, you can say `data Num cost => Edge a cost = Edge (Node a) (Node a) cost`. In my view that's a much better compromise between the awkwardness of tagging Int and Float and allowing arbitrary costs, but you don't need it - you can quite happily add the restriction just exactly when you need it on a function that combines costs with `+`.)

Your whole definitions would then be

```
data Node a = Node a
data Edge a cost = Edge (Node a) (Node a) cost
data Graph a c = Graph [Edge a c]
```

Again, you need to write `Graph [Edge a c]` because `Edge` takes two types, so has kind `* -> * -> *`.

Comment: Please have a look at boolean type: data Bool = True | False. So why I cannot define my Cost type as: data Cost = Int | Float. And a little bit confusion is what is the difference between : data Node a and data Node a = Node a ?

Comment: @chipbk10 It _is_ confusing, I agree. You could argue it's too confusing to be allowed to use the same name twice to mean two things, but people who've been doing it for years won't want to edit their code and would correctly point out that the compiler knows which is which - one `Node` only appears in type signatures, the other `Node` only appears in functions, so since it can tell them apart by location in code, it lets us use the same name, even when that's not the clearest way. Once you're more used to Haskell's types you'll be used to this "constructor pun" too.

Comment: @chipbk10 is my edit more helpful? If not, which bit doesn't make sense?

Comment: Thank you, but using "Num cost" when declaring Edge type is depreciated in Haskell, I got warning when compiling.

Comment: Then don't put `Num cost=>`.

Comment: I think the people who decided to deprecate it don't like it mainly because it's not GADTs (a very handy, very nice, but advanced language feature), and they have to keep typing `Num cost` every time they use the type, when they'd rather it was implicit, like in a GADT. I like to use it exactly when I want to be forced to type `Num cost` every time I use the type. For some tasks, the explicit restriction works well for me, but you don't have to use it, like I say. Without it you can have any cost, for example, `Char` or `Int -> String`.

Comment: @chipbk10 I updated the answer to this `Num`less version, but with Num mentioned in brackets. Does the rest make sense?